# Add space between date and time with moment.js

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I have a datetimes coming back from my database in ISO format. They look like this: `2015-11-03T10:06:50.000Z`. I am using moment.js to parse it out so that it's more readable and the result looks like this: `11-03-2015 10:06:50 AM`. I simply want to add another space between the date and time so it's easier to read. Any thoughts?

I've tried adding another space between the date and time in moment and it appears that it strips out all spaces except one. I've also tried hyphens and pipes but those don't really look the way I want.

```
rows.forEach(row => {
    // TODO find a way to put more blank space between date and time
    let formattedDateTime = moment.utc(row.DateTime).format(`MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss A`)
    row.DateTime = formattedDateTime
    // console.log('formatted datetime', formattedDateTime)
  })
```

Expected: adding spaces between the date and time in moment.format would reflect that way on the client.

Actual: only allowed one space between date and time. All other spaces are removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem of moment or vue, momentjs will add your white spaces as you add them (you can easily check by debugging your var or with console log) but your browser by default will collapse multiple spaces into only single space. Have a look at [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS property to learn more.

Also, you should not handle how the date will be displayed in your JS, it should be handled in your CSS. So my advice in your case is to separate date and time into 2 variables in your JS code and adapt your HTML template and CSS to display them properly.

Usually adding multiple spaces in your HTML code (and even more in your JS code) is not a good approach, you should instead achieve that with CSS.

Comment: @ReeseWesterhoff you're welcome. Don't forget to upvote the answer(s) that satisfied you and select an answer as the accepted one if that solved your problem. That will help further readers.

Answer (score 7):

have the same requirement, the solution is to use \xa0

moment(date).format('YYYY-MMM-DD\xa0\xa0\xa0HH:mm');

Answer (score 1):

Try using a template literal when assigning:

```
let d = moment.utc(row.DateTime)

row.DateTime = `${d.format('MM-DD-YYYY')}  ${d.format('hh:mm:ss A')}`
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that and added a ton of spaces but unfortunately it didn't work. It logs correctly in the console but I think Matt is right, the html is stripping the white space out.
     `let dateTime = moment.utc(row.DateTime)
        row.DateTime = ``${dateTime.format('MM-DD-YYYY ')}       ${dateTime.format('      hh:mm:ss A')}`

Comment: See @Matt's answer, it seems more likely the case.