# Moment.js with space as left padding instead of 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to create a column of times with text align center and is monospace font. I want the times to line up but I don't want hours less than 10 to have the leading 0. I am using moment-react to format the times. Is there a way to use a space as the leading padding instead of a 0?

```
const timeFormat = '?H:mm'
```

Looking the the moment.js docs, I didn't see anything about it so I'm thinking it's a no, but I just wanted to see if I was overlooking something.

Comment: I think it makes sense to just pick up the value and format the alignment from CSS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219346/add-space-between-date-and-time-with-moment-js/54220119. In any case, `H:mm` would work on it's own.

Comment: Also as a follow-up: if you can help it, move to Luxon and other alternatives. :)